# Hibernate criteria query on subclasses with same field name

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, criteria

Consider a class A that is the parent of B and C.

```
@Table(name = "a")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class A {}

@Table(name = "b")
public class B extends A {
  private String status;
}

@Table(name = "c")
public class C extends A {
  private String status;
}
```

Now when I do the following criteria query(for class a):

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("someString", status))
```

I have a similar setup in my project but the resulting query will not produce the correct result. Hibernate is using the status column of table b instead of table c (it seems it is not able to determine the correct one).

This is what the resulting native query looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM a outer join b on a.id = b.id outer join c on a.id = c.id WHERE b.status = "someStatus"
```

While to be functionally correct it should be

```
SELECT * FROM a outer join b on a.id = b.id outer join c on a.id = c.id WHERE (b.status = "someStatus" or c.status = "someStatus")
```

This is correct as only c or b will be non null, as in java it is impossible to have an entity that could be both b and c at the same time.

When doing a query on B.status the result is ok. While one might argue that it is bad design to use the same column name for it or start a discussion that this is a bug in hibernate or not I would like to know if there is some way to make it more clear to hibernate which table should be used.

Is there a way in hibernate / criteria to uniquely specify which subclass the field I am filtering on is in?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think you should have your "status" attribute on your class "a", in this way, b and c can inherit the same attribute. I can see you are using "InheritanceType.JOINED" strategy, then you should set an id to join both tables, something like this:

```
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="ID")
```

Now, you are joining two tables, but actually they are different tables, then if you want to filter some specific column, you have to indicate the correct table, thinking as database manager.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(b.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("someString", status));
```

I hope this information helps you.

Good luck.

Comment: Actually they are not the same status. In java they are both enums, different enum types, but in the db they are represented as a string (Example above is simplified). So having status in A is not an option. The join column and all that is ok, the code has been working for years but now I needed a search on status. The search is on type a so doing session.createCriteria(b.class) is not correct. The search is on session.createCriteria(a.class). As a workaround I renamed the instance variable status to something else in the c class.

Comment: how did you solve this problem?